# Problema con netbeans java length null exception

Tags: java

Que tengo mal? alguien me puede explicar por favor.

```
    public class Library  {
    book[] books=new book [20]

    public Library (){

    }
        public Library(int BookID,Student Name) {



      for (int i = 0; i < books.length; i++) {
        books[i].BookName= "unknow";
        books [i].BookCategory= "unknown";
        books [i].BookID= i;
}
Borrow(BookID,Name); 

        }

    public void Borrow (int BookID, Student st){


        if (search (BookID) != null) {
            System.out.println("The book is: "+search (BookID).BookName);
            System.out.println("The book has a category: "+ search (BookID).BookCategory);
            System.out.println("Borrowed to: "+ st.Name);
        } 
        else {
            System.out.println("This book does not exist");
                }
    }

    public book search (int BookNumber)
    {
        for (book book : books) {
            if (book.BookID == BookNumber) {
                return book;
            }
        }
    return null;
    }
    public void addBook (book nbook){
        for (int i = 0; i < books.length; i++) {
            if (books [i].BookName == null) {
                books [i]= nbook;
                break;
            }
        }

    }

        /**
         * @param args the command line arguments
         */

    }
```

El error que me sale

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at library.Library.(Library.java:23)

Comment: Cual es la linea 23?

Comment: Perdon habia una linea que faltaba que era la 23

Comment: La 23 es   
      for (int i = 0; i < books.length; i++) {
        books[i].BookName= "unknow";
        books [i].BookCategory= "unknown";
        books [i].BookID= i;

Comment: No me sirvio o no se que editar el problema esta en el for que os acabo de enviar

Comment: Pero yo hice este for para que no se quede en null, y aun asi me salta null? no lo entiendo

Comment: @Pablo Lozano tiene razón, **tu pregunta SÍ que está en esa respuesta.** El último punto lo dice: `No implica que el vector se llenara mágicamente de objetos de tipo1. Debes hacer un New tipo1 para cada posición del vector`

Comment: @C.Rodriguez podrias explicarme que es lo que tendo que cambiar?

Comment: Es decir, creaste tu vector de `book`, pero no has iniciado internamente dicho vector, debes crear un nuevo `book` antes de utilizar `book[i]`, si no te saltará `NullPointerException`

Comment: book[] books=new book [20]
Si que lo inicio

Comment: Iniciaste el vector, mas no has iniciado los valores internos, por defecto, **TODOS** son `null`. Lo que debes hacer (y espero que marquen esta respuesta como duplicada) es agregar esta linea debajo del `for`: `books[i] = new book();`

Comment: Perdon por duplicar, pero es que no lo entendi, y añadi lo que me diste debajo del for pero sige lanzandome errores de null exceptions

Comment: Revisa de nuevo el código, olvidé una `s`

Comment: quieres decir books? no la clase se llama book, de verdad es que no entiendo cual es el problema, se supone que reservo para mi array de books de tipo book 20 espacios que son nulls, y lo que quiero hacer con el for es dar algo que no se null, no entiendo que es lo que pasa, espero no ser molestia pero alguien me lo podria explicar, y vuelvo a pedir perdon si es duplicada

Comment: Sé que la clase se llama `book`, pero tu vector (array) se llama `books`. Antes de utilizar `books[i]` necesitas crear un objeto `book` en ese espacio (que por defecto es `null`). Por lo tanto `books[i] = new book();`, creará un nuevo `book` para que le asignes sus variables...

Comment: Ok entendi, muchas gracias :)